# restructuredText / Sphinx: explicit horizontal space

Tags: unicode, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

How can I explicitly insert a horizontal spacing in Sphinx/reStructuredText?

The original problem is that I want to have a vocalization sign ُ  to appear over space, but it is always displayed over the first letter of the next word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that is "U+064F : ARABIC DAMMA", it appears to be a combination character, which means, [if I read this correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21722729/what-is-the-difference-between-combining-characters-and-grapheme-extenders-i), that it cannot be displayed inline and separate from another character, unless you trick it out with a non-breaking space replacement.  I grabbed an [example from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6369049/how-do-i-write-the-multiplication-sign-in-restructuredtext-rest).

```
this is |damma| |nbsp| damma

.. |damma|  unicode:: U+064F .. ARABIC DAMMA
.. |nbsp|   unicode:: U+00A0 .. NO-BREAK SPACE
```

I was able to display it in isolation using either a `.. code-block::` directive or as its own paragraph.

```
.. code-block:: text

    ُ


ُ
```

[image: damma]